# Machine precision in Haskell

Tags: haskell, precision

I googled "Haskell machine precision" and didn't find any information about how to get the machine precision in Haskell. Is there a built-in way to get it?

Otherwise I implemented it as follows (I translated some C++ code found on a serious site):

```hs
machinePrecision :: Double
machinePrecision = until isSmall half 1.0
  where
    isSmall :: Double -> Bool
    isSmall x = 1.0 + x / 2.0 == 1.0
    half :: Double -> Double
    half x = x / 2.0
```

Is it a correct way to get the machine precision of double numbers in Haskell?

Comment: `Double` is... double-precision. `Float` is single-precision. These are terms defined by the IEEE754 spec, I'm pretty sure. Not much more to say about it than that.

Comment: @DanielWaner [the docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Double) say "It is desirable that this type be at least equal in range and precision to the IEEE double-precision type", but that doesn't mean it always is so or must be so.

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-limits-0.1.0.0/docs/Numeric-Limits.html

Comment: @n.m.Thanks. Looks like the answer.

Comment: "Machine precision" isn't necessarily a useful bit of information?  For large enough x, `x + 1 == x`.  Generally the ulp of a value is more useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some packages, including `ieee754` and `numeric-limits` define a value `epsilon` that is the smallest representable `x` such that `1` and `1+x` can be distinguished.  That appears to be the `machinePrecision` value you're trying to calculate.

You can use these packages if you want, but you can also just use the two-line definition:

```
epsilon :: Double
epsilon = 2.2204460492503131e-16
```

It will never be anything else, notwithstanding any documentation in the `Prelude` about hypothetical `Double`s that aren't IEEE754 doubles.

If you need an equivalent value for `Float` the definition is:

```
epsilon :: Float
epsilon = 1.19209290e-07
```

These definitions are exactly the same ones used in the `ieee754` package, except in that package they're instances of a class method.

The values in Lennart Augustsson's `numeric-limits` package are calculated on the fly using `encodeFloat` and `decodeFloat`, a principled but "somewhat excessive" approach.

You can also use the following alternative definitions, which are equivalent:

```
epsilon :: Double
epsilon = 2**(-52)

epsilon :: Float
epsilon = 2**(-23)
```

If you are worried about portability to other Haskell implementations, start by patting yourself on the back for being one of the eight people on the planet writing Haskell for non-GHC targets, and then take comfort in the fact that there are no existing Haskell implementations whose `Double` is something other than an IEEE double.